# A Short Phowosquaddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme, word-square

> My first is a journey on the sea
>   At the resistance should my second be
>   Third is a short little, drawing knot
>   Backwards in the clock the fourth I spot

Hint:

> Obviously, the title contains a big hint. And *wosquaddle* is quite understandable. But what is *pho*? What clue might contain *-pho-*?

**UPDATE 23/7**
Since this is incredibly difficult, I guess I must reveal the main idea of the puzzle.

> Puzzled Pig's guess about *-pho-* is correct! They are indeed homophones. All of the 4 words have real meanings, however, none of them is mentioned (even implicitly) in the riddle. Instead, there is a meaning for a word (or phrase) which sounds the same as the word in the word-square.

Comment: "But what is *pho*?" Pho is a Vietnamese noodle soup. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *think* I might be onto the right square, but the *explanation* might not be complete.

> `S A L E`
>  `A T O M`
>  `L O T I`
>  `E M I T`
>
> ***[Edit: Initial guess for line 3 was LOKI]***

Explanation:

> 1. A homophone of *journey on the sea* (**Sail**);
>
>  2. A soundalike of *At the resistance* = **At+Ohm** (unit of resistance);
>
>  3. The one I'm struggling with a bit; the god Loki *is* a homophone, of **Low-key**, which *kind of* fits 'short' and 'little', but I'm not sure what a drawing knot is [***Edit:*** Actually, I got a letter wrong here. This word should be **LOTI**, the plural of lotus and a homophone of **Low** + **Tie** ('short' & 'knot'), as per the OP's explanation in the comments];
>
>  4. *Backwards in the clock* = The word **Time** spelled backwards, but it's not really a homophone.

Comment: Short = little = 'low', draw = knot = 'tie'. The homophone of it is "LOTI" the plural of lotus. The rest is correct!

Comment: Ah... shucks. Thanks for explaining, though! Glad I was *mostly* on target ;)

Comment: @Walt Give it the green check, then!

Comment: @feelinferrety Well, I'm not the OP. ;) But I fixed the answer according to the OP's original intention.

Comment: Gah, stupid. I picked the wrong W for the auto tagging. U_U

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really fit but might get a bit of discussion going:

> `S A I L`
>  `A E R O`
>  `I R I S`
>  `L O S T`

I feel there may be something I'm missing to do with:

> The lack of rhyme between lines 3 and 4 and the somewhat unusual title

**Edit:** Also had this one almost:

> `O R C A`
>  `R   E N`
>  `C E L T`
>  `A N T I`

Comment: Well an iris is kind of a knot like muscle that draws itself together and you can be lost in time. As I said doesn't really fit much at all but might point someone in the right direction.

Comment: The title seems like a shortened version of "Four word square riddle"

Comment: Ah that makes sense!

Comment: All 4 words are wrong :p Sorry for the bad rhyme, I'll try to improve it when I have time. By the way, @Christoph got the title wrongly interpreted. If this is too hard, I'll probably change the title later on.

Comment: In that case I'm guessing there is more to this than one would initially think. I thought for sure sail would be correct... The title appears to have the R and letter after removed from each word so that could hint to the answer being words with R? removed eg. cruise -> cise. I can't really see anything else that will let me piece this one together at the moment. Hopefully someone else can make some more progress.

Comment: @JamesCoyle: Now that's a good observation! (I thought that Pho-- could mean phonetic word square, so that the first word would be sale, but that didn't get me anywhere.)

Comment: what about phonograms? instead of fowosquaddle, its phowosquaddle. pho is the word-phonogram equivalent of how to pronounce the fo in four.

Comment: Or (following OP's hint) are we perhaps dealing with homophones?